# How to redirect all MediaWiki red links to a single URL

Tags: mediawiki

I would like to redirect all links to non-existing wiki pages to another single URL outside of my MediaWiki instance.  I'd like to avoid writing my own extension for this; i.e., there should be a way to do this with a simple configuration, yet the documentation doesn't really say.

Comment: You may not need to write a full-blown extension, but I'm pretty sure you do need to write a MediaWiki hook to do this.

Comment: Do you want to redirect the links at `Special:WantedPages`, or all “red” links, on any page?

Comment: All "red" links on any wiki page.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of a config option for this, but you can use the [`LinkEnd` hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/LinkEnd) and check for the "broken" option:

```
$wgHooks['LinkEnd'][] = function( $dummy, Title $target, array $options, &$html, array &$attribs, &$ret )
{
    if( in_array( 'broken', $options ) ) $attribs['href'] = 'http://yourlinkhere';
    return true;
};
```

This can be placed in `LocalSettings.php` directly without having to edit any other files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible out of the box with MediaWiki, but you could of course just include a bit of javascript that intercepts clicks on redlinks:

```
$('a.new').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com';
});
```

MediaWiki comes with jQuery by default, so this should work without any further changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I was able to accomplish by doing the following (MediaWiki 1.28):

- set up a new template e.g. "Template:Preload"
- install "MultiBoilerplate" extension https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Extension:MultiBoilerplate
- for "MultiBoilerplate" extension, add dropdown to new page with option to load template "Template:Preload" in *LocalSettings.php*:

`$wgMultiBoilerplateOptions[ "New page template" ] = "Template:Preload";`

- in *LocalSettings.php*, add the following code which checks if a link is to a new page, and adds the querystring parameter to default to the template above:

`# if a link is to create a new page, add querystring parameter to pre-populate with template
$wgHooks["HtmlPageLinkRendererBegin"][] = function( $dummy, $target, &$html, &$customAttribs, &$query, &$options, &$ret ) {
  # if the target does not exist
  $exists = $target -> exists();
  if ( !$exists ) {
    # add querystring parameter to set template, which will pre-populate empty new page
    $query["boilerplate"] = "Template:Preload";
  }
  return true;
};`

Adapted from https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/LinkBegin